# Sublime Text Custom Syntax Higlighting

Tags: sublime-text, latextools

How can I customize the syntax highlighting for both the arguments and optional arguments? For example: `\todo[inline]{some notes here}`. I would like to customize the color of text inside square brackets, as well as the text inside curly brackets. (I am using `LaTeXTools` package.)